# G++64 compiled executables "can't run on this PC" on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, g++

The title really says quite a bit, but let me give some context.

I am trying to work on coding without relying on an IDE like `Visual Studio`, so please **don't** suggest that I simply use an IDE to fix my problems.

Additionally, I **will not accept suggestions** that I use something other than `G++` to compile my code with. That's not a solution to my problem, that's an alternative path completely, and not one I wish to use.

So far, I have installed `MinGW-64`, and am using `g++64` to compile my software. For some reason, my code compiles flawlessly, but upon execution, `Windows 10` tells me `"This app can't run on your PC"`. Upon inspecting the Event Viewer, the error is that the program `"cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit Windows."` That doesn't make much sense to me, considering I'm compiling it with a `64-bit compiler`. However, I am reasonably new to programming and to using the `GNU toolchain`, so perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly.

Here is my current command to compile from command line:

`g++64 -c -Ic:\code\cpp\projects\git_test\include opengl_test.cpp -o opengl_test.exe`

Perhaps there is something with `OpenGL, FreeGLUT or GLEW` that is causing the issue?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I took the suggestion to remove the `-c` option, and now I'm getting a lot of undefined reference errors. I tried to add the libraries, but it doesn't appear to work, even though the files are clearly in the folder I've added.

Here is my new command to compile:

`g++64 -LC:\code\cpp\projects\git_test\lib -IC:\code\cpp\projects\git_test\include -lfreeglut -lglew32 -lglew32s opengl_test.cpp -o opengl_test.exe`

Comment: Lose the `-c` option. When you add that, your *exe* is actually an object file.

Comment: Are you running from a 64-bit cmd prompt (the one in windows\system32) or a 32-bit cmd promt (the one in windows\syswow64)

Comment: "now I'm getting a lot of undefined reference errors" post both them and the code that you are compiling - *in another question*. This one has already been solved, although in a comment.

Comment: Every lib you add to your executable must be compiled for 64 bits. Check that for glew & freeglut.